# Compare 2 ArrayLists and remove duplicates

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I am looking to compare values of 2 different ArrayLists, and remove any duplicates from 1 ArrayList.

Example:

Arr1 = {HF,HA,GM,RV}

Arr2 = {FB,HA}

Since they have 'HA' in common, I would like to remove 'HA' from Arr1. Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's Except but you will have to convert array lists to regular arrays first:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    Dim list1 As New ArrayList()
    list1.Add("A")
    list1.Add("B")
    list1.Add("C")

    Dim list2 As New ArrayList()
    list2.Add("A")
    list2.Add("B")

    Dim array1 = list1.ToArray()
    Dim array2 = list2.ToArray()
    Dim except = array1.Except(array2).ToArray()
```

[image]

Also if you need a custom comparison, use this overload instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT**

There are very few LINQ methods available for `ArrayList`, however you can convert it back very easily:

`Dim arrayList as New ArrayList(except)`

Comment: Is there a way to do with ArrayLists?  Converting to an Array would mean more changes elsewhere that I would like to avoid.  Or would converting the Arrays back to an ArrayList do the trick?